# Printing out hello world with assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I had just started to learn assembly and some lower level concepts (I have some higher level background with python, js, etc).

I am trying to print out hello world with the following assembly program:

```
section .data
    msg db 'Hello World'
    len equ $ - msg

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    MOV rdi, 1 ; stdin fd
    MOV rsi, msg
    MOV rdx, len
    MOV rax, 1 ; write syscall
    INT 0x80
```

I am running Ubuntu Linux on an x86_64 machine.

I assembled the program with nasm: `nasm -f elf64 hello_world.nasm`

Then I then linked with `ld`: `ld -o hello_world hello_world.o`

When I run `./hello_world` nothing is printed out to the console.

Comment: Where did you get this code from?  Why are you using `int 0x80` to do a 64 bit system call?

Comment: I just looked at a bunch of guides online and tried to do something on my own. What would be the correct way to do it?

Comment: Use a `syscall` instruction.  `int 0x80` is for 32 bit mode.  You'll also need to add an exit system call after the write system call so your program actually terminates the normal way.

Comment: There's some discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46087731/2189500), but in general, 64bit should use syscall, not int 80.  Note: The function numbers and registers are different for syscall than int 80.

Comment: You have the call-number and arg registers for the 64-bit `syscall` ABI, but then you used `int 0x80` which looks at EBX, ECX, and EDX.  (And where EAX=1 is `_exit`).  Just replace it with `syscall`!  On an-to-date system, `strace ./hello_world` should properly decode the 32-bit system call you make.